# Find a string in an image and return its X,Y coordination

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ocr

I have an image and I want to extract the X and Y coordination of a specific string in it.

say a map as here;

then for example I need to have coordination of 'London' in X, Y.

```
h = figure; 
I = imread('C:\MyPath\openSt.jpg');
xImg = linspace(0, 50, size(I, 2));
yImg = linspace(0, 50, size(I, 1));
image(xImg, yImg, I, 'CDataMapping', 'scaled');
hold on;
```

[image]

Is it possible to do it using OCR?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: of course it is possible to recognize characters using OCR. Recognizing characters in images is the only purpose of Optical Character Recognition...
Most methods will provide coordinate information along with the string.

Comment: Thanks, actually I didn't manage to get coordination in a figure, but the important issue is the quality of image, I intend to use OpenStreetMap or Google map as an image. This kind of image have very low resolution and the results of "ocr.Words" are not as correct as needed.

Comment: so the image you provided does not represent the images you actually want to use? that wouldn't be very helfpul. and why would you read google map maps as an image? you know there is an API right?

Comment: Yes the image could be exactly like this above.
You mean a free Google API which provides interface with Matlab too?

Comment: don't limit yourself to matlab... who says you cannot use something else or at least something that provides the data for matlab?
you get the coordinates from matlab anyway https://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ocr.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com
they provide the character bounding boxes. so I'm not sure what your problem is. if matlab cannot read your images due to quality and you stick to matlab you are doomed

Comment: What I want to have is basically an additional feature for my main analysis and graph(representing power system), that are done already in Matlab. That's why I thought it is could be one of the solutions.
By the way you are right, it seems to be difficult doing that in Matlab.